# CSS bootstrap fill left part of navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I have to implement a complex navigation styling.

I succeeded to simplify the problem to show only the part of the html.
The problem is that I cannot touch the HTML code.

Here is the code (a simple bootstrap navbar):
https://jsfiddle.net/5y4asdef/

I want to fill the space in left of "Application name" for example with white color is such way that to work on all resolutions especially (wider)

I've tried something like this:

```
.navbar-header:after {
    content: " ";
    background-color: white;
    width: 110px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left:  0px;
    top: 0;
}
```

I've tried with combining some background properties, but couldn't figure out how to apply it.

I want to ensure that no matter of how long is the screen it will work:
https://jsfiddle.net/5y4asdef/show `(fullscreen)`

Answer (score 0):

Use **.container-fluid** class instead of **.container**

Here's the updated snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the "application name" should remain where it was. Now it is on the left on all resolutions. thanks for the effort, but It's not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my non-quality solution for now:

```
.navbar-header {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-header:after {
    content: " ";
    background-color: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    top: -6px;
}
```